# gradle 3.2 failed to sync in android studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, http-status-code-407

i just downloaded the android studio 3.2 and it cannot sync my new project gradle.
i m using a proxy and i entered the proxy details in setting too. but i get this error:

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

i downloaded the file with google chrome.
when i use the 'offline mode' in gradle , i get this error:

```
No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

what should i do?

Comment: Is your internet is working??  make sure you connected to internet then try building the gradle it will download dependancies and problem will be resolve.

Comment: yes it works and i can download the that file by chrome but i cant do it by android studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i added this proxy details to the gradle.properties and it worked.
if you wanna find gradle.properties go to C:\Users\youruser.gradle  and you find it.

```
    systemProp.http.proxyPort=your port 
systemProp.http.proxyUser=vpn username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=vpnpass
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=vpn pass
systemProp.https.proxyHost=vpn ip
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.http.proxyHost=vpn ip
systemProp.https.proxyPort=your port
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.https.proxyUser=vpn username
```

sometimes if you use your username and password in android studio setting, it doesn't work.

///////////
*****first check if the android studio can use your proxy without giving it the information.you can check the (no proxy) box in setting>appearance and behavior>system setting>http proxy, and try to rebuild the project

Answer (score 1):

Go to :

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
```

And then uncheck the `offline work`.

Comment: i did that but it said:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: If it is unchecked and you're not in offline mode, it should work. Otherwise, check your internet connection. You probably checked the offline work that's why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have idea on running offline mode do this.

1. Go to folder that you have already created project (build using online mode) for example C:\users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\project1.
2. After that create a new project in Android Studio. And build it in offline mode.
3. It shows same error. Now copy the .gradle and app folderfrom first project folder to second project folder.
4. Now build and sinc project it will run perfectly.
5. For this you should have atleast one "Hello World" project already build using online mode. After that copy this for all other projects.